# what would the critical points be of this equation?

Tags: calculus

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-4x}{(1+x^2)^2}$

i just dont understand how find them with a reciprocal function.  If someone could explain how to find it in this this situation that would be fantasic!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A critical point is the point at which the sign (+ or -) of a function's slope changes from positive to negative. Since $f(x) = \dfrac{-4x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ is actually the derivative of the function: $$F(x) = \int\dfrac{-4x}{(1+x^2)^2} = \dfrac{-2}{1+x^2}+C$$ which looks like this (where $C=0$):
[image: 2/(1+x^2)]
The point at the center of the red circle is the critical point. If you wanted to solve it mathematically instead of visually, in order to be able to find all critical points on an infinite interval, you would take the derivative of that function and set it equal to $0$
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\Big(\dfrac{-2}{1+x^2}+C\Big) = \dfrac{-4x}{(1+x^2)^2} = 0
$$
You then solve for x. Since $x^2\neq-1$ for all values of $x$, the denominator can be ignored. We are then left with:
$$-4x = 0$$
$$x = 0$$
so the x value of your critical point is at $x=0$. You then plug this value back into $F(x)$ to get the get your critical point:
$$\Big(0,F(0)\Big)$$
The reason this works is because a derivative is just the mathematical way of saying `rate of change`. A critical point is the point where a function changes from increasing to decreasing or vice versa. That point between increasing and decreasing is exactly where it is neither increasing, nor decreasing. Therefor its rate of change at that point is $0$, so its derivative is equal to $0$. Therefor taking the functions derivative, setting it equal to $0$, and solving for $x$ gives you the point at which the function is neither increasing or decreasing, also known as its **Critical Point**.

Answer (score 1):

The critical point of a function is a value of $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that either $f'(x)$ is $0$ or undefined. From your equation, $f'(x) = 0 \to x = 0$, and $f'(x)$ is always defined for all $x$. So $x = 0$ is the only critical value.